# How to efficiently apply a binary function to select columns of 2 tables and only to rows based on some conditions?

Tags: matlab

What is the most efficient way to apply a binary function to some columns of two table?

For example, let

```
var1=[1;2;3;4];
var2=[1;1;1;3];
A=table(var1,var2);

var1=[2;3;4;5];
var2=[1;1;1;3];
B=table(var1,var2);
```

If I want the new table C where

```
C=table(func(A.var1,B.var1),var2);
```

with for example `func=@mean`,

what is the most efficient way to achieve the result? Is `[bsxfun(@func,A(:,1),B(:,1),var2)]` efficient?

In my application, I need to first remove rows where `var2` is 0 and where `A.var2` and `B.var2` are non-identical. I am using syntax like `A=A(A.var2~=0,:)` and `[~,ia,ic]=intersect(A.var2,B.var2); A=A(ia,:)`. And `func` would be a combination of the above two steps and `[mean(A(:,1),B(:,1)),var2)]` before using `bsxfun`. However, at that point, I've effectively looped over the columns of each table for 3 times. Is there a more efficient way with built-in functions to apply a binary function to select columns of 2 tables based on some conditions?

Comment: the term binary took me by surprise. I was expecting indexing... but built-in functions seems about right. Anyway.... how do you interpret *efficient*? Is is memory or computation? If you go for computation, I usually measure the time calling a toy example 10000times

Comment: @max: Primarily computation. In this application, I am waiting in front of the computer for each call to complete. But I also have a fairly pedestrian computer with only 32GB RAM and with a lot of things running. It would be troublesome if every 10000-by-6 array takes up 100MB.

Comment: To my experience loops are the fastest and most efficient way to deal with arrays, matrices in MATLAB (you should limit your computation to those data structures if memory is an issue). You will abstain from using the handy vector-wise computing if you are really digging into efficiency... everything that implicitly extend something is bad, and even implicit looping (e.g. by multiplying two arrays) is slower than writing a loop. Nevertheless, I recommend to use the vector-computation as a standard. `bsxfun`, `arrayfun` shouldn't be faster than a loop, it's just nicer for reading sometimes

Comment: @max: I did some experiments. And the result of the experiment is to avoid `cellfun` in favor of looping. I think the reason you find looping quicker is due to compile time (or the lack of). There should be more overhead with looping than with vector functions. When using `arrayfun`, `cellfun`, there is a good chance the code is not pre-compiled and does not get the benefit from JIT. And that's probably why no one consider these two vector functions.